# How come ldd reference appears twice for openssl binary?

Tags: c++, linker, binary, openssl, ldd

For some reason reference to libcrypto appears twice while executing "ldd".
Why? does the binary selects the second instance of libcrypto?

```
root# ldd openssl | grep libcrypto
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 =>    /server/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 =>    /lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

Comment: `ls` should show `/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0` is the real file; while `libcrypto.so` and `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` are symlinks.

Comment: I have this file twice on my system, is should use /server/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0

Comment: why does it shows libcrypto.so.1.0.0 file twice? like the pointer(libcrypto.so.1.0.0) is beeing set twice